# Pass @EventListener to Component via Vuejs Router

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

Before I used [vuejs-router](https://router.vuejs.org/en/), I've loaded component in app this way:

```
<my-component @done="doneForm"
              @cancel="cancelForm"></my-component>
```

Well, I want to use `vuejs-router` to load `my-component`. So, how can I pass `@done` and `@cancel` to `my-component` via `vuejs-router`?

Comment: Vue router is a routing engine, it's not for loading components. You need to load a route to a component then load that component in the way you are with your callbacks.

Comment: Tnx for the reply, do you mean that I use the vuejs-router in one component (instead of vuejs app) and load `my-component` in that component by routes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define a route to which your `my-component` will be instantiated. This component will contain the `done` and `cancel` callbacks, so:

```
var router = new VueRouter({
  routes: [
    { path: '/someRoute', component: SomeComponent }
  ]
]
```

`SomeComponent` would be something like:

```
<template>
    <my-component @done="doneForm" @cancel="cancelForm"></my-component>
</template>
<script>
    import MyComponent from '/some/path/components/MyComponent'

    export default {
        components: {
            myComponent: MyComponent
        },
        methods: {
            doneForm () {
                console.log('Form Done')
            },
            cancelForm () {
                console.log('Cancel Form')
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

As you've not shown any code and how you're calling your `<my-component>` but the whole point is that the `<my-component>` needs to be instantiated somewhere within another component that can have hold the `cancelForm` and `doneForm` methods. If you didn't want these callbacks then you could set a route up to go straight to that component.

Another option is to make thing stateful using Vuex. You could remove the callbacks from the component and when the form is done within `<my-component>` set something in the state that you can react to somewhere else in your app. You could also do the same with events and raise an event to listen for and do something.

Comment: I like the first way :)